# Script for identifying a country

Tags: php

I'm in a bit of a trouble. I have developed a script, which finds a users country. The script returns the native version of the country; eg. Denmark (English) is Danmark (Danish) on the server. Is there a fast way to convert it to English?

Comment: Could you post some code please

Comment: It is currently not possible to post some code, since the server receives the country from an app with the $_GET['country']

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. For me it's not clear what your actual issue is. Do you need to replace a string?

Comment: I am not sure, but this might give you something to work from: http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfCultureInfo

Comment: Diverse locale based function can be found in the Intl package, e.g. like [`Locale::acceptFromHttp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.acceptfromhttp.php) or [`Locale::getDisplayLanguage`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.getdisplaylanguage.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to put the time in to build a dataset. Once you have this information in a database, queries will be easy and you won't have to rely on outside influence to your script.

[This site](http://www.omniglot.com/countries/) should get you started. Click on each individual country and it shows its English name and its name in it's local language.